# Can we remove Memory Optimized file group from database

Tags: sql-server

I checked In sql server 2019(15.0.2070.41) and tried to remove with bellow mentioned command:

```
Alter database InMemoryCheckpoint 
Remove file InMemoryCheckpointDF 

Alter database InMemoryCheckpoint 
Remove filegroup InMemoryCheckpointDF
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't remove a memory-optimized filegroup.

> The following limitations apply to a memory-optimized filegroup:
>
> Once you use a memory-optimized filegroup, you can only remove it by
>   dropping the database. In a production environment, it is unlikely
>   that you will need to remove the memory-optimized filegroup.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/the-memory-optimized-filegroup?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I have 300 plus tenants after the memory optimization implementation when we try to restart `sql service` max of the database is in recovery mode. Now i am trying to remove file group but it's throwing error is there any other way to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

### !!! Please use this method in case of corrupted database that contains memory optimized table (you can't use DBCC check on databases that contains memory optimized tables) !!!

### WARNING: This is an unsupported operation. There have been reports of unrecoverable log corruption when using this.

### It's a hack method and it's risky. Microsoft didn't verified this solution

### Before doing anything take backup

1- Delete memory optimized tables

2- Detach Database

3- Create new database with same files without memory optimized filegroup

4- Modify database files and change it to detached database (mdf,ldf,ndf) files

```
alter database test1 modify file (name='test1' , filename='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf')

alter database test1 modify file (name='test1_log' , filename='C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_log.ldf')
```

5- Now try to to repair database:

```
alter database test1 set emergency

alter database test1 set single_user with ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

dbcc checkdb(test1,repair_allow_data_loss)

alter database test1 set multi_user

alter database test1 set online
```

6- After successfully repair database remove memory optimized filegroup from database

```
ALTER DATABASE [test1] REMOVE FILEGROUP [memory_optimized_filegroup_0]
```

> Follow steps correctly for prevent log corruption
>
> Step 4: Alter log file name must be done correctly
> Step 5: DBCC is Important to prevent corruption
>
> Also for getting best result:
>
> Don't use database while doing steps (Insert - Update - Changing
> Schema)
>
> do CHECKPOINT to flush log to data file then shrink log file
>
> you will never have log corruption issue

### Don't forget:

### Before using your database do this steps for checking issue:

1. Insert or update 1 row in database
2. Do CHECKPOINT
3. Restart server

### If database got online i think you did all steps correctly else Restore database from backup and forget about removing memory optimized filegroup

Comment: Shitty solution, database corrupted

Comment: I'm sure you didn't follow steps correctly.
every steps are important

Answer (score -3):

Used these commands and they worked fine for me:

```
USE [<dbname>]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [<dbname>]  REMOVE FILE [<filename>]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [<dbname>] REMOVE FILEGROUP [<Group Name>]
GO
```